# why does java infer serializable on passing the arraylist object of string to generic method

Tags: java

1. `static <T> T pick(T a1, T a2) { return a2; }`
2. `Serializable s = pick("d", new ArrayList<String>());`

if I am making the reference to String or any other type. Compiler is throwing an error .

Could you please help me understand why does java infer it to Serializable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- As argument `a1`, you're passing `"d"` of type `String`.
- As argument `a2`, you're passing `new ArrayList<String>()` of type `ArrayList<String>`

The nearest common supertype of String and ArrayList is `Serializable`.
It would also work if you wrote:

```
Object s = pick("d", new ArrayList<String>());
```

Comment: Thanks Erwin. Does that mean that String class implements Serializable interface in standard java packages? Does the java infer algorithm work like this since class A and class B both implements common interface say C then for above sceanrio the return type would be C?

Comment: @user35253 Both string and Arraylist directly/indirectly implement a Serializable interface. To answer your question the return type is not necessarily to be C. It can be of any type.

Answer (score 0):

In function *pick* result has same type as parameters *a1* and *a2*. 
At second line Java compiler tries to infer common type *T1* for both arguments *a1* and *a2*. Result of function call will be have type *T1*.
So, *a1* has type *String* and *a2* has type *ArrayList*. Both these types implements interface *Serializable*. Hence *T1* will be inherited from *Serializable* and you can write *Serializable* at start of second line.
You can't write there *String* because *String* is not common supertype for both *String* and *ArrayList*.